# How to check if my app is being debugged in android?

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging

Is there a way to check within my android application if it's being debugged, like a DEBUG flag or somthing? I want to print a special message when the application is being debugged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There are two ways to check if the apk is being debugged or not**

**1. BuildConfig.DEBUG:**

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) { 
    // do something with debug build
}
```

**Note:** If you are using the first one then make sure BuildConfig is imported from your project or your app.

**2.ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE**

```
if (0 != (getApplicationInfo().flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE)) {
     //Debug APK
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use **BuildConfig.DEBUG**. This is a boolean value that will be true for a debug build, false otherwise:

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
  // do something with debug build
}
```